# How to configure source compatbility level for xtend-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, xtend

Follow-up of [Is there a P2 repository with an up-to-date javassist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446390/is-there-a-p2-repository-with-an-up-to-date-javassist)

The issue I have is related to Java lambdas. I am also using xtend, and xtend lambdas are generated as Java lambdas if source level compatibility is set to Java 8+, but as anonymous classes.

I know how to set the source compatibility level in Eclipse, but how do I configure it for xtend-maven-plugin? I did not find documentation.

Comment: Have you set the correct source and target for the maven compiler plugin?

Comment: @JFMeier What you are saying is I should just put source level 1.8 and target level 1.7 in maven compiler plugin? I'll try that.

Comment: Why not both 1.8? I don't think source level can be higher than target level.

Comment: @JFMeier Both ARE 1.8 right now, the issue is that I have an outdated javassist version which has issues with 1.8 lambdas. I am getting my javassist from Orbit and would like to avoid having to handle P2 metadata myself if I can help it, so I am looking for a workaround instead of updating javassist (which includes some work on P2 metadata).

Comment: Ok, then just forget my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is with xtend 2.20.

The 2.14.0 answer did not work for me. I had to use

```
<configuration>
    <javaSourceVersion>1.8</javaSourceVersion>
</configuration>
```

in my pom file to force the xtend maven plugin to produce Java 8 code instead of the default, which is Java 1.6.

Comment: Can you say which xtend version this is? I will add the xtend version to my answer, too. This way others will have an easier time to figure out which property needs to be used.

Answer (score 1):

### How to set source level compatibility for xtend-maven-plugin 2.14.0

The property for this is `maven.compiler.source`.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
        <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

### How I found this information

Maybe this can help someone in the future: Since this plugin has next to no documentation, I went to the [Mojo source code](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-xtend/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtend.maven.plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/xtend/maven/AbstractXtendCompilerMojo.java) and found:

```
/**
 * Create Java Source Code that is compatible to this Java version.
 * 
 * Supported values: 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 9 and 10
 */
@Parameter(property="maven.compiler.source", defaultValue="1.6")
private String javaSourceVersion;
```